# Spark - word count using java

Tags: java, apache-spark, word-count

I'm quite new to Spark and I would like to extract features (basically count of words) from a text file using the `Dataset` class. I have read the ["Extracting, transforming and selecting features"](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html) tutorial on Spark  but every example reported starts from a bag of words defined "on the fly". I have tried several times to generate the same kind of Dataset starting from a text file but I have always failed. Here is my code:

```java
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
              .builder()
              .appName("Simple application")
              .config("spark.master", "local")
              .getOrCreate();

Dataset<String> textFile = spark.read()
            .textFile("myFile.txt")
            .as(Encoders.STRING());

Dataset<Row> words = textFile.flatMap(s -> {
    return  Arrays.asList(s.toLowerCase().split("AG")).iterator();
    }, Encoders.STRING()).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).toDF();

Word2Vec word2Vec = new Word2Vec()
      .setInputCol("value")
      .setOutputCol("result")
      .setVectorSize(16)
      .setMinCount(0);

Word2VecModel model = word2Vec.fit(words);
Dataset<Row> result = model.transform(words);
```

I get this error message: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column value must be of type equal to one of the following types: [ArrayType(StringType,true), ArrayType(StringType,false)] but was actually of type StringType.`

I think I have to convert each line into a Row using something like:

```java
RowFactory.create(0.0, line)
```

but I cannot figure out how to do that.

Basically, I was trying to train a classification system based on word counts of strings generated from a long sequence of characters. My text file contains one sequence per line so I need to split and count them for each row (the sub-strings are called k-mers and a general description can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-mer)). Depending on the length of the k-mers I could have more than 4^32 different strings, so I was looking for a scalable machine learning algorithm like Spark.

Comment: Can you please add full stack and contents of text file.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count occurences of words, you can do:

```
Dataset<String> words = textFile.flatMap(s -> {
return  Arrays.asList(s.toLowerCase().split("AG")).iterator();
}, Encoders.STRING()).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty());

Dataset<Row> counts = words.toDF("word").groupBy(col("word")).count();
```

Word2Vec is much more powerful ML algorithm, in your case it's not necessary to use it. Remember to add `import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;` at the beggining of the file